# How to use the Google account from my app's users to make maps api calls?

Tags: java, html, json, xml, api

I am trying to make calls to the google maps api. That's not really a problem in itself. In my Android app, I would like to make api calls to google to get location data for nearby restaurants.

From my own research, I have found that this is not too difficult when using my own api key. However, this would mean that any user of my app will cause me to use my monthly maps api call limit.

Is there a way for users of my app to "sign in with google" and somehow get their own api key so that each user has their own and I don't have to spend my api limit on my app users? There does not seem to be documentation on the matter when I did some research (maybe because it is not possible?). Maybe its just a matter of me using wrong search terms.

Comment: OAuth2 might help you.